# Capturing pipe symbol delimited digits with regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to capture the digits (ids) from a "|" delimited string,
This is an example string:

```
|98|34|2|{"flag":"CHART"}
```

This is the expression that seem to work (for the first digit)

```
^\|(\d+)\|
```

The problem is that this only captures the first digit.

I don't know how to make this regex repeat itself till it reaches the "{" symbol.
Help would be appreciated!

And please tell me if there is a more efficient way to do this (in php)

Comment: How about `explode()` to split the fields and then to treat the fields according to their expected type? Regular expressions are a tool, but they are not always the best tool for a task...

Comment: This works, but then I need to filter all the results and when my JSON contains a "|" symbol it will be an issue.

Comment: Why are you mixing different metaformats anyway? Why not use JSON all the way instead? Still, if the number of `|`-wrapped fields is constants, use the third (optional) parameter to just extract those and keep the rest as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\G` anchor to start the next match on the same string where the last match left off.

```
(?:^\||\G)\|?(\d+)(?=\|)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uJ7wA6/2)

Comment: It doesn't capture last `4`

Comment: Yes because it's next to the curly  brace.